# Как создать несколько процессов потомков от одного родителя и запустить их параллельно?

Tags: c, многопоточность, процесс, fork

Пытаюсь понять как рождаются процессы от родителя через fork. Накидал вот такой вот код.

```
int i;
int it;
pid_t pid[10];

pid[0] = fork();

printf("Parent I:%d\n",getpid());


     for(i = 1; i<=5; i++)
     {
        pid[i] = fork();
        sleep(1 + rand() % 5);
        if (pid[i] ==0){
           printf("CHILD I:%d \n", i);
           exit(0);
        }
        else{
          wait(&ut);
        }
      }
    
       return 0;
 }
```

В выводе у меня принтуется PID родителя(возможно это вообще не нужно и неправильно), и после вызывается последовательно 5 потомков:

```
  CHILD I:1
  CHILD I:2
  CHILD I:3
  CHILD I:4
  CHILD I:5
```

Вопрос, правильно ли я вообще запустил процесс наследования от одного родителя и как запустить эти процессы параллельно с задержкой, например:

```
  CHILD I:5
  CHILD I:4
  CHILD I:1
  CHILD I:2
  CHILD I:3
```

Вроде получилось сделать как нужно, но все еще есть сомнения по поводу асинхронных выполнений процессов

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main() {
FILE *inputFile;
inputFile = fopen("in.txt", "r");
char charsArray[128];
int i;
int it;
int t;
pid_t pid[10];

printf("Parent I:%d\n",getppid());
printf("__________\n");
srand(time(NULL));
if (inputFile == NULL) {
    perror("Error while opening file");
    }
else {

    for(i = 1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        t = 1 + rand() % 7;
        pid[i] = fork();

        if (pid[i] ==0){
            sleep(t);
            printf("CHILD I:%d Time: %d\n", i, t);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
wait(&it);
sleep(7);
fclose(inputFile);
}
return 0;
}
```

Вот вывод:

```
 Parent I:3696
 __________
 CHILD I:1 Time: 1
 CHILD I:6 Time: 1
 CHILD I:7 Time: 1
 CHILD I:3 Time: 2
 CHILD I:2 Time: 3
 CHILD I:8 Time: 3
 CHILD I:10 Time: 4
 CHILD I:4 Time: 5
 CHILD I:5 Time: 6
 CHILD I:9 Time: 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код не компилируется, но выглядит похожим на правду. Только вы запускаете процессы последовательно, потому что ждёте завершения одного ребёнка прежде чем запустить следующего. Запускать и ждать надо в разных циклах:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 5

void child(int i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        printf("child %d(%d): %d\n", i, (int)getpid(), j);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    pid_t pids[N];

    puts("parent start");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            child(i);
            exit(0);
        } else {
            pids[i] = pid;
        }
    }

    puts("parent wait");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (pids[i] > 0) {
            waitpid(pids[i], NULL, 0);
        }
    }

    puts("parent stop");
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.c
>
> $./a.out 
> parent start
> child 0(14003): 0
> parent wait
> child 3(14006): 0
> child 2(14005): 0
> child 4(14007): 0
> child 1(14004): 0
> child 0(14003): 1
> child 2(14005): 1
> child 3(14006): 1
> child 4(14007): 1
> child 1(14004): 1
> child 0(14003): 2
> child 3(14006): 2
> child 4(14007): 2
> child 2(14005): 2
> child 1(14004): 2
> child 0(14003): 3
> child 3(14006): 3
> child 4(14007): 3
> child 2(14005): 3
> child 1(14004): 3
> child 0(14003): 4
> child 3(14006): 4
> child 4(14007): 4
> child 2(14005): 4
> child 1(14004): 4
> parent stop
> ```

Comment: Спасибо, у меня, правда, получилось сделать что-то подобное, только в одном цикле, добавил код в основной вопрос. Хотелось бы у вас уточнить, сделал ли я все верно ?

Comment: Запустили процессы вы верно. Ждёте непонятно чего - `wait` ждёт завершения последнего запущеного ребёнка. Если он закончится раньше других, отцовский процесс завершится пока работают некоторые дети. Это место у вас исправлено (замазано) семисекундным ожиданием. Ждать надо честно.